# How to use MSSQL to Row concatenate?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this row concatenation question has been asked before but I cannot find answers that will solve my problem.  I have an older AS400/DB2 database that I am using an Excel ODBC connector to get to the data.  I have used MySQL in the past but this is my firstt attempt at MSSQL.  To set up the question I have the following:
A work order number (wono)
A note line number (ntlno1)
A note data 50 character text length (ntda)

For each wono you can have several line numbers (ntlno1) and each line number can have up to 50 characters of data (ntda).  I need to be able to concatenate all of the ntda data into one field by work order number and note line number.  Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT WOHDR.wono AS WONO, WONOT.ntlno1 AS NoteLineNo, substring((Select ','+WONOT.ntda  AS [text()]
            From libd09.wopnote0 WONOT
            Where WONOT.wono = WOHDR.wono
            ORDER BY WONOT.wono
            For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) [wopnote0]

FROM libd09.wophdrs0 WOHDR 
LEFT JOIN libd09.wopsegs0 WOSEG ON (WOHDR.wono = WOSEG.wono)
LEFT JOIN libd09.cslusrp0 USR ON (WOSEG.clsdby = USR.uspfid)
LEFT JOIN libd09.woplabr0 WOLBR ON (WOHDR.wono = WOLBR.wono)
LEFT JOIN libd09.wopnote0 WONOT ON (WOHDR.wono = WONOT.wono)
LEFT JOIN libd09.wopmisc0 WOMISC ON (WOHDR.wono = WOMISC.wono)
LEFT JOIN libd09.wopempf0 WOEMP ON (WOMISC.epidno = WOEMP.epidno)
LEFT JOIN libd09.woppart0 WOPART ON (WOHDR.wono = WOPART.wono)
LEFT JOIN tafilev22.employ01 TAEMP ON (WOMISC.epidno = TAEMP.ememp)

WHERE WOHDR.opndt8 BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I have only included the pertinent columns though the joins have all the tables that I need.  when I run the query I get the following error: Token [ was not valid.  Valid tokens: .

I am sure I am missing something simple so any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove the `AS [text()]` part and try executing the query.

Comment: Also try using `STUFF` instead of substring to get a comma separated value for the `wopnote0` field.

Comment: Hello...when I removed the    AS [text()] part I get the following error: SQL0104 - Token was not valid.  Valid tokens:, FROM INTO.

Comment: Had an extra bracket so I changed it to: `SELECT DISTINCT WOHDR.wono AS WONO, WONOT.ntlno1 AS NoteLineNo, substring((Select ','+WONOT.ntda AS Comments FROM libd09.wopnote0 WONOT WHERE WONOT.wono = WOHDR.wono ORDER BY WONOT.wono For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) [wopnote0] FROM libd09.wophdrs0 WOHDR` and now it does not like keyword ORDER not expected. Valid tokens: ) UNION EXCEPT.

Comment: The reason is that `ORDER BY` is allowed only on the outermost query. That is the reason I asked you to try STUFF instead of SUBSTRING. Try something like `STUFF((Select ',' + WONOT.ntda  AS [text()] From libd09.wopnote0 WONOT Where WONOT.wono = WOHDR.wono   ORDER BY WONOT.wono For XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')` to select `wopnote0`.

Comment: I made the changes using STUFF and MS SQL did not like the brackets around text() so I removed them and now I get the following error: Token ( was not valid.  Valid tokens: , FROM INTO. I checked all of the parentheses and I have matching pairs.  This is how the query now starts   `SELECT 
DISTINCT WOHDR.wono, STUFF((Select ',' + WONOT.ntda AS text() FROM libd09.wopnote0 WONOT Where WONOT.wono = WOHDR.wono ORDER BY WONOT.wono For XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
`